# AWK Sum and group by : output with headers

Tags: awk

I have a huge csv with this structure (sample):

```
| DATE | WEEKDAY   | Shop Code   |Shop Manager|Item Presentation Time|Item Sell|

|02-Mar |MONDAY    |  BOG        | Tom        |1030                  |0        |

|02-Mar |TUESDAY   |  TEF        | Lucas      |1300                  |1        |

|02-Mar |WEDNESDAY |  TDC        | Eriberto   |1300                  |1        |

|02-Mar |THURSDAY  |  TEF        | Lucas      |1300                  |1        |

|02-Mar |FRIDAY    |  TEF        | Lucas      |1300                  |1        |

|02-Mar |SATURDAY  |  GTY        | Maya       |1600                  |1        |
                                         
|02-Mar |SUNDAY    |  TDC        | Eriberto   |1300                  |1        |
```

I am interested in the sum of successful event ($6)per weekday, the count of presentation per weekday ($2),  and the percentual of successful event ( sum $6/count $2 *100)
I wrote the following script:

```
#!/bin/awk -f

BEGIN {FS = OFS = ","}

{if (NR!=1)  a[$2]+=$6;count[$2]++$2}END{for (i in a){ print i","a[i] "," count[i]","a[i]/count[i]*100}}
```

The script runs:

```
$ awk -f script.awk raw_file.csv > new_file.csv
```

It works out perfectly and  the output is:

```
|MONDAY    |  2     | 10    |0.20|

|TUESDAY   |  18    | 30    |0.60|
                 
|WEDNESDAY |  10    | 20    |0.50|
                
|THURSDAY  |  1     | 20    |0.05|
                  
|FRIDAY    |  1     | 15    |0.07|
                
|SATURDAY  |  60    | 100   |0.60| 
                                                         
|SUNDAY    |  47    | 80    |0.59|
```

However I would like to add in the output the header (WEEKDAY,SUCCESSFUL_EVENTS,TOTAL_EVENTS and SUCCESSFUL_RATE. I have no idea how to put in the same script the NR with the header.
I can show the output with:

```
awk 'NR==1 {print 
"WEEKDAY","SUCCESSFUL_EVENTS","TOTAL_EVENTS","SUCCESSFUL_RATE"}{print 
$0}' new_file.csv
```

but no way to integrate this in the script

Any suggestion is really appreciated

Comment: Click on the [tag:awk] tag below your question, then click the "Learn more" link to learn how awk works. A little research will answer your question.

Comment: Do you **really** have a blank line between every data line in your input/output? Also you should your input/output as `|`-separated but then say it's CSV and set FS and OFS to `,` - please fix so everything in your question uses whatever separator you actually have in your data.

Comment: Thanks Glenn for your suggestion.

Comment: @EdMorton Hello. I am new in awk and stack overflow. I put as separator |  because I saw the formatting guide. In the original file the separator is , . Still not confident with formatting, I will be better. Thanks!

Comment: Not sure what you saw in  the formatting guide but whatever you provide as sample input/output in your question is what we can then copy/paste to test a potential solution with so never adjust it to try to make it appear better in any way as then you're likely to end up with a solution to a problem you don't have! Just indent your sample input, expected output, and code by 4 blanks or put 3 ticks before and after each, that's all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in the begin section of your script:

```
#!/bin/awk -f

BEGIN {
  FS = OFS = ","
  print "WEEKDAY", "SUCCESSFUL_EVENTS", "TOTAL_EVENTS", "SUCCESSFUL_RATE"
}
#  ...
```